# Need a script that continues to refresh a page even when user leaves Browser in Android or phone screen goes blank

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have use:

```
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "3";
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

and

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
</script>
```

to refresh my page on an android device. However, it stops refreshing if I leave the browser or my phone screen turns off. How can I keep refreshing?

Comment: Why do you need to refresh it if you're not looking at it? I don't think the browser runs javascript when the browser's not open... you might have to write that kind of data-fetch as an app with background data permission.

Comment: this makes little sense, what's the the 'big picture' here?

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a vehicle tracking system. I need to keep getting the location of a user using Google Maps API. The refresh is used to keep receiving current location every few seconds and store the location in a database system to tally up the distance in Miles.

Comment: you need an app installed on the users phone, not a website